# Converting an array to pointer for memcpy

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memcpy

I have two arrays, `a` and `b`, both of length `x` bytes.  I need to use `memcpy` to copy the memory from `a` to `b`.  What is the correct syntax to use, since `memcpy` takes in two `void*` as its argument? Is it:

```
memcpy(&a[0], &b[0], x);
```

Comment: You  mean from **b** to **a**?

Comment: in memcpy() the first argument is the address of the first byte of the destination.  the second argument is the address of the first byte of the source.  the third argument is the number of bytes to copy.   Note:  your posted code copies from 'b' to 'a' while that actual question is saying to copy from 'a' to 'b'

Answer (score 4):

To copy `x` bytes from `a` to `b`, you'd say:

```
memcpy(b, a, x);
```

`memcpy()` takes the destination first, then the source.

Array names evaluate to the array address when used as parameters, and `void *` parameters will accept any pointer you throw at them.

```
memcpy(&b[0], &a[0], x);
```

would be equivalent, but needlessly verbose.